# Unsupported or unrecognized ssl-message exception at startHandshake after issuing STARTTLS command in a java program

Tags: java, ssl, starttls

I have written a simple e-mail client in java without using the JavaMail API, as by what I read from the documentation it seems necessary to split the messages up into head and body and in the single MIME-parts for sending which would make my application a lot more complicated. Everything worked fine for a SSL port (465) but now I'm trying to use the client with a different provider that only supports STARTTLS on port 587. The following code is of a class I wrote to test the access to the server.

```
private static DataOutputStream dos; //Streams to communicate with the server
private static DataInputStream dis;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("mail.arcor.de", 587);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        new Thread(() -> {readInputRun();}).start(); //see below, every input from the server is printed to the standard output.

        dos.write(("EHLO " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "\r\n").getBytes());

        dos.write("STARTTLS\r\n".getBytes());

        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(socket, "mail.arcor.de", 587, true);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());

        sslSocket.startHandshake();

        dos.write(("EHLO " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "\r\n").getBytes());

        dos.write("QUIT\r\n".getBytes());

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void readInputRun() {
    try {
        int input;
        while((input = dis.read()) >= 0) {
            System.out.print((char) input);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Every time I execute it, I get the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:416)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:173)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1031)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at accessTest.AccessTestSTARTTLS.main(AccessTestSTARTTLS.java:31)
```

It is thrown at line 31, which is 'sslSocket.startHandshake();', so somehow the handshake does not work out. Do I initiate it at the wrong point or in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: As suggested in the comment, I enabled the logs and found the following:
[httpslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IitSc.png). In the fifth but last line there is an unreadable character, obviously as part of the client hello, so my computer sends it. Why is this the case and how can I stop that?

Comment: enable the https logs and take a look at what happens as a first step. See [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: Read the responses to EHLO and STARTTLS before doing the SSL./TLS handshake.

Comment: I already ran the code in debug mode line by line and waited for the readInputRun() method to read the server input completely before initiating the handshake. Did not change anything.

Comment: Why? Do you seriously think Javamail doesn't exist for a reason? Don't waste your time reinventing the wheel. Other and greater men have been there before you. If you want to see further, stand on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: This is not about reinventing the wheel, it is about understanding how the protocols used for e-mail transfer work.

Comment: If you want as secure code as JavaMail, you're not going to finish soon.

Comment: Okay, your log shows it: your `readInputRun` thread is reading not only the (text-mode) responses to EHLO and STARTTLS but also the first byte of the ServerHello message (which is hex 16 aka control-V) before JSSE can get it; since JSSE gets a garbled and unrecognizable ServerHello it cannot proceed. I revise: read the responses to EHLO and STARTTLS **and only those responses NOT any part of the SSL/TLS handshake**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem. I actually misinterpreted the output and thought that the unreadable character was part of the log forgetting that the readInputRun() was still writing. I wanted to add that I really appreciate to get a useful answer after all those 'don't waste your time'-comments.

Comment: Follow up to make it re-entrant and correct: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/65362799/13770150>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the main intention behind this answer is to mark the question as answered, because actually the solution is found in the comments to the question. The problem lies in the readInputRun() that reads part of the ServerHello, so letting the reading thread interrupt itself before the handshake and restarting it after it solves it:

```
dos.write("STARTTLS\r\n".getBytes());

SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(socket, "mail.arcor.de", 587, true);
dos = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
dis = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());

sslSocket.startHandshake();

new Thread(() -> {readInputRun();}).start();

dos.write(("EHLO " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "\r\n").getBytes());

dos.write("QUIT\r\n".getBytes());
```

and:

```
private static void readInputRun() {
    try {
        int input;
        String allInput = "";
        while((input = dis.read()) >= 0) {
            allInput += (char) input;
            System.out.print(allInput.charAt(allInput.length() - 1));

            if(allInput.endsWith("Start TLS\r\n")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```